# How to get value of a cell in html page when click to a link in list link?

Tags: arraylist, web-scraping, html-table, hyperlink, cell

I have a list about 5000 link.
Ex 2 in 5000 link:

https://racevietnam.com/runner/buiducninh/ecopark-marathon-2019

https://racevietnam.com/runner/drtungnguyen83/ecopark-marathon-2019

...

I want to get value of column **Time of Day** and row **Finish** of links.

Ex:

**09:51:07 AM** - https://racevietnam.com/runner/buiducninh/ecopark-marathon-2019

**07:50:55 AM** - https://racevietnam.com/runner/ngocsondknb/ecopark-marathon-2019

I got user infor of a website, that website has id, class. But table in https://racevietnam.com/runner/ngocsondknb/ecopark-marathon-2019 have not id, class in table. So I can't.

```
#!/usr/bin/python
from urllib.request import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

list_user = []

for userID in range(1, 100000):
    link = "https://example.com/member.php?u=" + str(userID)
    html = urlopen(link)
    bsObj = BeautifulSoup(html, "lxml")
    user_name = bsObj.find("div", {"id":"main_userinfo"}).h1.get_text()
    list_user.append(user_name)
    print("username", userID, "is: ", user_name)
    with open("result.txt", "a") as myfile:
        myfile.write(user_name)
```

Please help me.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is my code.
It's working Ok.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

f = open("input.ecopark","r")
f_content = f.readlines()
f.close()

for url in f_content:
    r = requests.get(url.rstrip())
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')
    result = soup.select("table tbody tr td")
    x = ""
    for i in result:
        if not x:
            if i.get_text() == "Finish":
                x = 1
                continue
        if x:
            print(url.rstrip()+ " "+i.get_text())
            break
```

Answer (score 1):

Using bs4 4.7.1.

There is only one table and you want the second column (`td`) of the last row. You can use `last:child` to select the last row; which should be used in conjunction with `tbody` type selector, and `>` child combinator, so as not to get header row. You can use `nth-of-type` to specify the `td` cell to return.

Now you may wish to develop this in at least two ways:

1. Handle cases where not found e.g.

```
name = getattr(soup.select_one('title'), 'text', 'N/A')
timing = getattr(soup.select_one('tbody > tr:last-child td:nth-of-type(2)'), 'text', 'N/A')
```

2. Add items to lists/data structure, which can be output as a dataframe at end and written out as csv. Or you may wish to stick with your current method

Python:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

urls = ['https://racevietnam.com/runner/buiducninh/ecopark-marathon-2019', 'https://racevietnam.com/runner/drtungnguyen83/ecopark-marathon-2019']

with requests.Session() as s:
    for url in urls:
        r = s.get(url)
        soup = bs(r.content, 'lxml')
        name = soup.select_one('title').text
        timing = soup.select_one('tbody > tr:last-child td:nth-of-type(2)').text
        print(name, timing)
```